# breadcrumbs in wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

Lets say i have a webpage, pageA, which is a child of pageB which is in turn a child of page C

Could i make a breadcrumb trail for this page by iteratively getting the parent page of the page until the page has no parent? When the page has no parent I add 'home' so the final breadcrumb would be

Home >> page c >> page b >> page A

If i had a page, page D which was a child of page E which had no parent the breadcrumb would be

Home >> page E >> page D

I have looked on line but can only find what seems to be really complicated code to make breadcrumbs. I only need to get the title, url and parent page of a page, and then keep moving back up the chain as it were

thanks a lot

Comment: There are a ton of breadcrumbs plugins for WP that do exactly this.  Use one of them.  Alternately you can write it yourself by calling the global `$post` object, testing for `$post->post_parent` and querying by post ID on up the chain until you reach the top level.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like standard breadcrumbs to me.

It's much better to use a plugin that already exists than recreate the wheel.

This one seems to be popular - 1 million+ downloads.

[Breadcrumbs Navxt Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/breadcrumb-navxt/)